# In $\Delta ABC$, $AB=√17$, $BC=5$, $CA=4√2$. There are points $D,E,F$ on lines $AB,BC,CA$ forming another $\Delta DEF$ inside $\Delta ABC$

Tags: geometry

In a triangle $ABC,$ $AB = \sqrt{17}, BC = 5, CA = 4\sqrt2.$ There are points $D, E, F$ on lines $AB, BC$ and $CA$ respectively, forming another triangle $DEF$ inside $ABC.$ Minimum perimeter of DEF is $(q/p)\sqrt{34},$ what is the value of $p + q?$
 (Given that $p$ and $q$ both are positive numbers and have no common factors)

[image: image of Triangle]

1. 35
2. 36
3. 37
4. 38
5. 39

Note: I translated this from Korean. [Original question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgkzi.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems like there isn’t enough information here. The perimeter can take a lot of values under this condition.

Comment: You probably want $p,q$ having no common facts, not that they don’t divide each other. $6$ and $4$ don’t divide each other, but they have a common factor.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Sorry I have translated this question from Korean so made that mistake. Is it okay now?

Comment: You should show your effort to get help. The problem is well-defined (I believe, $p$ and $q$ are positive integers and have no common integer positive factors except 1). The problem does not need the picture to present and it certainly does not need the answer options. Hint: you can use vectors or coordinates to solve this problem.

Comment: Or you can just find in the Internet the fact, that (acute triangle)-inscribed triangle with minimum perimeter is orthic triangle.

Comment: Prove that your triangle is a acute-angled triangle and use the Fagnano's problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagnano%27s_problem

Answer (score 1):

The orthic triangle has the minimum perimeter of any triangle inscribed in a given acute triangle (Johnson).
https://mathworld.wolfram.com

$\begin{array}{} s_{H}=\frac{Δ}{R} & R=\frac{abc}{4Δ}  \end{array}$

where $s_{H}$ is semiperimeter of $ΔDEF$, $Δ$ is the triangle area of $ΔABC$, $R$ is the circumradius

$Perimeter_{DEF}=2·s_{H}=\frac{8Δ^2}{abc}$

$BE=1$, $CE=4$, $AC=4\sqrt{2}$⇒$AE=4=h_{A}$⇒$Δ=10$

$Perimeter_{DEF}=\frac{8·10^2}{5·4\sqrt{2}·\sqrt{17}}=\frac{20}{17}\sqrt{34}$

$p+q=37$